# Core Data: Creating Relationships

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am wondering if anyone would be kind enough to help me with a core data related problem. I am building a iPhone app and now need to create a relationship from one entity to another.

I am new to core data, objective c and quite frankly the whole app development process so if you do have an answer please bare in mind I may find it hard to understand :-( I have spent a very long time scanning the web and reading Apple's documentation and just can't get my head around this problem.

---

I am trying to insert new data into an entity and make a relationship to an existing object in a different entity. I have set up my data model, created my NSManagedObjectSubClasses and can insert and manage data into a single entity, I just can't working out how use relationships.

For example, let's say I have an Entity named `Article` and another named `Author`. I already have a list of authors. When I create a new article how do I link this new article to an already existing author with a relationship?

**What line(s) of code do I need to create this relationship?**

**What information do I need to create that link?**

I have a feeling my problem is with the type of data I'm trying to create the relationship with. NSIndexPath, NSManagedObject and NSMutableSet don't seem to be right.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You create the relationship as part of designing the entities, not in lines of code.  Assuming you want the ability to have an article with more than one author, you need to look at a many-to-many type of relationship.  (Author would have a to-many relationship called articles and Article would have a to-many relationship called authors that was its inverse.)

You could then create Author and Article subclasses and the code to link their objects would be something like: `[myAuthor addArticlesObject:myArticle];`.

For example:

```
Author *myAuthor = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Author"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
myAuthor.name = @"Phillip Mills";
Article *myArticle = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Article"
                                                   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
myArticle.title = @"Sample of linking core data entities";

NSError *error;
[myAuthor addArticlesObject:myArticle];
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Database update failed: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. I have a similar setup to what you have described. The part I can't seem to grasp is the "myArticle" section? What is it? would you be able to break down your line of code for me please?

Comment: `myArticle` and `myAuthor` are assumed to be objects that have been created using `NSEntityDescription`'s `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` method.  If the relationship has been set up right, the `addArticlesObject` should exist in the `Author` class.

Comment: Thank you again, I think I'm getting there but I'm now getting the error: "No known class method for selector 'addArticlesObject:'" Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: If it's complaining about a "class method" then you're probably using the Author class rather than an object in the place where I have `myAuthor`.  I'll edit my answer with a code sample.

Comment: Now I'm getting duplicate authors in my database, any ideas?

Comment: That's entirely up to your code.  If you already have one in the database that matches what you need, use it (`executeFetchRequest`) instead of creating a new one.  As far as Core Data is concerned, each new object you create is unique; the fact that some attribute (like 'name') might be the same isn't its concern.

Comment: Right I'll give that a go. Thanks for helping I'll give your answer a tick to let you know if it works :-D

Comment: Hi Phillip, I'm sorry but I am still struggling to get my head around this. Would it be possible for you to update your answer with another code example? It would really mean a lot to me, thanks.

Comment: Why not something like myArticle.author = myAuthor;

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Something like that would work if you had a system where an article could only have a single author.

Comment: I'm still stuck on trying to link my article to an already existing author in my database. With the current method I create a new Author every time which is quite a problem for me :-(

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239797/core-data-unique-attributes, especially the first answer that shows how to either fetch an object or create a new one depending on whether what you want already exists.