# Swift Importing Large JSON data Set and Core Data

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

What would be the best approach to performing a large JSON data request and storing it in Core Data?

I am currently getting a JSON file from the server which contains a list of jobs with associated entities, I am then parsing it and populating a Core Data Entity, which works fine.

When the user refreshes their list I will be performing a fresh request to the server so I assume I will need to completely remove all existing entities and repopulate the DB.

How is this kind of operation best achieved in Swift?

I have found a couple of tutorials and examples using Dataseeding which seems close enough.

If you need some examples or existing code please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered many many times on Stack Overflow.  You are wanting to import data and then on a refresh you want to solve the classic insert/update problem.

You want to be doing this import on a background thread to avoid interrupting your UI.

You do not want to delete all objects. You want to use KVC to get all the IDs from the incoming JSON then do a single fetch against CD to find out what already exists.

You then want to iterate over the JSON, inserting if it doesn't already exist and updating when it does exist.

Since your UI should be using a `NSFetchedResultsController`, you will then just need to save your private `NSManagedObjectContext` and your UI will update as a result.

Comment: you are right, I just wasn't sure if those answers solved this particular situation. turns out it does. If Core data doesnt use ID's then how do you map the key values?

Don't suppose you have a link to a tut or example?

Comment: You create a property on your objects that store that ID.  They are your objects and the ID is a business value not a Core Data value.

Comment: As for an example, all of the ones I have posted are out of date.  Expect a new post from me in the next month (waiting on external influences to post it).

Comment: would you recommend using a library such as restkit?

Comment: I do not recommend using any third party libraries.  Core Data is already an abstraction layer.  Adding another does not make sense.  Best to write the tiny amount of code required, learn how everything works and be able to maintain your own app all the way down to the Apple level.  Core Data and NSURLSession are not hard to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Groot](https://github.com/gonzalezreal/Groot). It provides a simple way of serializing Core Data object graphs from or into JSON without adding any abstraction layer on top of Core Data.

Comment: thanks, yeah i did look at that but as Marcus mentioned above, I have found it better to try not to rely on a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueness has been introduced for Core Data in iOS9. So you don't have to use `NSFetchedResultsController` and compare/purge the old data.

You just have to do this:

```
managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
```

You can find a more detailed answer here - [How to add unique constraints for some fields in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130427/how-to-add-unique-constraints-for-some-fields-in-core-data)