# Grasping Core Data's uniqueness constraints

Tags: xcode, core-data, unique

I'm working with Core Data and the iTunesLibrary framework in a macOS application. During startup, I import information (on my iTunes tracks) from iTunesLibrary.

Media-items in iTunes have unique identifiers (namely the `persistentId` on class `ITLibMediaItem`) so in my Core-Data store I use this information as a unique attribute on the `Song` entity, that represents an iTunes track in my model.

I've marked this attribute (called `iTunesID` on my `Song` entity) as unique, using Xcode, and I have verified that the constraint is also present, when viewing the raw XML (given in the .xcdatamodel-file) in a text-editor.

If I run my program twice (leading it to import the same data twice), no errors occur on save, and I later verify that the number of elements in the store has doubled. Let me point out, that what I want is to prevent having  objects in my store, that represents identical information.

However, I then tested further and had my program try to save two objects (with the same information in them, and specifically identical `iTunesID`s) into my context during startup, and here Core-Data *does* throw an error, saying a uniqueness constraint was violated.

**Main-Question**

It seems that Core-Data respects uniqueness constraints *among objects about to be inserted*, while it does not respect uniqueness constraints among *an object that is about to be inserted and one that is already in the store*...Is this understanding correct?

Btw, I'm using the default merge policy (`errorMergePolicyType`) on my `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.

**Additional question**

I'm using a String-representation of the iTunesPersistentID, since I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130427/how-to-add-unique-constraints-for-some-fields-in-core-data), that uniqueness constraints only work on String-attributes in Core-Data; can someone reject/confirm this?

```
// This leads to the number of elements in my store growing, each time I run my program
for song in songsFromiTunes
    {
        // Create and insert a managed object into context
        let managedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Song", into: managedObjectContext) as! Song
        if let artistName = song.artist?.name
        {
            managedObject.artist = artistName
        }

        managedObject.title = song.title
        let iTunesIdentifier = "\(song.persistentID.int64Value)"
        managedObject.iTunesID = iTunesIdentifier
        if let title = song.album.title
        {
            managedObject.album = title
        }
    }
```

Inserting an entity with the same `iTunesID` twice, leading the subsequent `save()` on `managedObjectContext` to throw an error

```
for _ in 0...1
    {
        let managedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Song", into: managedObjectContext) as! Song
        managedObject.artist = "Someone"

        managedObject.title = "Title"
        managedObject.iTunesID = "A String"
        managedObject.album = "AlbumTitle"
```