# How to debug Core data unique constraint violation crash happening on context.save()?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an entity named **Score** , which represent a day wise score. This entity has two properties `date: Double` and `score: Double` . Here **date** is the midnight timestamp epoch of a day.
I've followed this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130427/how-to-add-unique-constraints-for-some-fields-in-core-data) answer to add **date** as a unique constraint to this entity.

So my code looks like this:

```
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    var factor1: Double = 0
    var factor2: Double = 0
    var factor3: Double = 0
    
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    calculateFactor1(date: date) { score in
        factor1 = score
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
   
   dispatchGroup.enter()
   calculateFactor2(date: date) { score in
        factor2 = score
        dispatchGroup.leave()
   }

   dispatchGroup.enter()
    calculateFactor3(date: date) { score in
        factor3 = score
        dispatchGroup.leave()
   }
    
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        let mainScore = factor1 + factor2 + factor3
        let scoreObject = Score(context: self.context)
        scoreObject.date = date
        scoreObject.score = mainScore
        
        do {
            try self.context.save()
            completion()
        }
        catch {
            completion()
        }
    }
```

but this code crashes on `context.save` with an error:
`Constraint unique violation: UNIQUE constraint failed: ZSCORE.ZDATE`

How can I debug this?

Comment: I wouldn’t use data as unique constraint. You can use a random UUID as primary key

Comment: In my use case each day(date = midnight epoch) is assigned a score, hence making **date** as a unique property made sense to me.
But i'm curious as how having a UUID will help solve this issue?

Comment: Il’ there is some useful info [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/ensuring-core-data-objects-are-unique-using-constraints) : basically, specifying a merge policy to the container.

Comment: Turn on Core Data debug logging and see what happens at an SQL level by adding this Run argument to you scheme `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 4`

Comment: Have you checked to see if your `notify` closure gets called more than once? That would cause the problem you’re seeing.

Comment: Something is definitely amiss in the way you're using the dispatch group. You enter once but leave three times. That would cause a crash on its own.

Comment: My Bad on dispatch enters, missed adding those in the question, but in actual code number of enters =  number of leaves